# Some men and women are randomly assigned seats at a round table and no two persons of the same sex are seated next to each other. Probability of this?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Four women and four men are assigned seats at random at a round table. what is the probability that no two persons of the same sex will be sitting next to each other?

Comment: How many ways are there to choose $4$ seats on which to put "Reserved for Women" signs? How many of these choices lead to no two people of the same sex being next to each other?

Comment: the number of choices lead to no two people of the same sex being next to each other = 2

Comment: the number of ways are there to choose 4 seats on which to put "Reserved for Women" signs = 8C4

Comment: i think that the probability p = 2 / (8C4)

Comment: Hi. Could you please share more of the work you put into this question? It seems like a fairly standard homework question.

Comment: @emmie: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the seats are numbered sequentially  from 1 to 8, with Seats 1 and 8 also being adjacent.

Without loss of generality, assign the first male to Seat #1

Then Seats 2 and 8 are forbidden for further male assignment.

Also, assigning a male to Seats 4 or 6 would leave either two females seated adjacent in the gap (2 & 3 or 7 & 8), or a male seated next to an previously seated male.

In short, all male must be in odd seats, all females in even seats...

So, first male is assigned any seat, defining the numbering system origin.

Second male has 3 possible out of 7 available, third has 2 out of 6 and the fourth has 1 out of 5.  Probability of P$$P=\frac37 \times \frac26 \times \frac15$$Remaining quests sit wherever there is a slot...

Answer (score 1):

All $\binom84$ choices for the seats for the women are equiprobable, and there are only $2$ choices such that they sit in alternating seats; thus the desired probability is

$$
\frac2{\binom84}=\frac1{35}\;.
$$